# Extending the ServerPartT Monad with a Reader

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, happstack

I am writing a Happstack server and I have a MongoDB database to connect to. For that, I made a function to create a connection pool

```
type MongoPool = Pool IOError Pipe

withMongo :: (MongoPool -> IO a) -> IO ()
withMongo f = do
    pool <- dbPool
    f pool
    killAll pool
```

And then a function to run an `Action` with a created pool:

```
runDB :: (MonadIO m) => MongoPool -> Action IO a -> m (Either Failure a)
runDB pool f = liftIO $ do
    pipe <- runIOE $ aResource pool
    access pipe master dbName f
```

It's obvious this requires to carry the `pool` in all the routes as a parameter. I would like to wrap it into a `ReaderT`, so that `runDB` can have a type like `Action IO a -> ServerPart (Either Failure a)` or even better, `Action IO a -> ServerPart a` in which a failure will result in an HTTP Error 500 automatically.

I have a trouble wrapping my head around how that can be achieved and I'd love for some hints from people who've more experience with Haskell monads and happstack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through this question I found another with a very good hint, and I have built this. It seems to work fine and I thought I'd share it:

```
type MongoPool = Pool IOError Pipe

type DBServerPart a = ReaderT MongoPool (ServerPartT IO) a

hostName = "127.0.0.1"

dbName = "test"

defaultPoolSize = 10

runDB :: Action IO a -> DBServerPart (Either Failure a)
runDB f = do
    pool <- ask
    liftIO $ do
        pipe <- runIOE $ aResource pool
        access pipe master dbName f

withMongo :: DBServerPart a -> ServerPart a
withMongo f = do
    pool <- liftIO $ dbPool
    a <- runReaderT f pool
    liftIO $ killAll pool
    return a

dbPool = newPool fac defaultPoolSize
    where fac = Factory {
            newResource = connect $ host hostName,
            killResource = close,
            isExpired = isClosed
        }
```

Comment: That looks right to me. The other option is to do, `type DBServerPart a = ServerPartT (ReaderT MongoPool IO) a`, and then use `mapServerPartT` to flatten it to `ServerPartT IO`. The is little difference between to two solutions. Though this method will allow you to leverage the `XMLGenerator` instance for `ServerPartT` if you use `HSX`. Mostly it doesn't matter which way you do it though.